# SneakyInput / SneakyButton

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently experimenting with various input controls and have stumbled upon SneakyInput, which I am trying to play with.

Unfortunately, when I am adding a SneakyButton (just a button) to the layer, the whole app crashes with the following error message:

`+[CCTouchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:priority:swallowsTouches:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xfed9c
2012-01-30 10:00:50.881 OpenSpace[588:1be03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[CCTouchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:priority:swallowsTouches:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xfed9c'`

I have banged my head around this for several hours and have tried googling for a solution with very little joy. Any help here would be appreciated, why, why does it crash?

Environment: Cocos2d 2.0 beta, OS X 10.7.2, iOS 5.0

Code:

```
-(void) addFireButton {
float buttonRadius = 80;
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

fireButton = [[[SneakyButton alloc] initWithRect:CGRectZero] autorelease];
fireButton.radius = buttonRadius;
fireButton.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width - buttonRadius, buttonRadius);
[self addChild:fireButton];
}
```

Error Message Full:

```
2012-01-30 10:00:50.684 OpenSpace[588:1be03] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0-beta2
2012-01-30 10:00:50.685 OpenSpace[588:1be03] cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
[Switching to process 588 thread 0x1f113]
2012-01-30 10:00:50.763 OpenSpace[588:1be03] cocos2d: animation started with frame interval: 60.00
2012-01-30 10:00:50.766 OpenSpace[588:1be03] cocos2d: surface size: 960x640
2012-01-30 10:00:50.850 OpenSpace[588:1be03] init: <OpenSpace = 093BFAE0 | Tag = -1>
2012-01-30 10:00:50.857 OpenSpace[588:1be03] cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: spaceship-hd.png
2012-01-30 10:00:50.864 OpenSpace[588:1be03] +[CCTouchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:priority:swallowsTouches:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xfed9c
2012-01-30 10:00:50.881 OpenSpace[588:1be03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[CCTouchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:priority:swallowsTouches:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xfed9c'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c4c052 0x21e2d0a 0x1c4dadd 0x1bb2f00 0x1bb2ce2 0xb5438 0x1c4de1a 0x99e19 0x99dba 0x42890 0x345ed 0x1c4de1a 0x99e19 0x99dba 0x42890 0x26edd 0x90d7d 0x921c4 0x2a12db 0x2a11af 0x1c20966 0x1c20407 0x1b837c0 0x1b82db4 0x1b82ccb 0x29fd879 0x29fd93e 0x822a9b 0xb37d6 0x2525)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 588 thread 0x1be03]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language: auto; currently objective-c
```

Comment: Perhaps this is the reason why, from the docu to cocos2d v2.0: CCActionManager, CCScheduler, CCTouchDispathcer (iOS) and CCEventDispatcher (Mac) are NO LONGER singletons. Instead, they are properties of CCDirector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally managed to solve this problem, for those interested the solution lies in replacing all references to CCTouchDispatcher to a property of CCDirector. In Version 2.0 of cocos2d CCTouchDispatcher is no longer a singleton, yet a property of CCDirector.

I have forked the SneakyInput Library on github and added my fixes there directly

https://github.com/clops/SneakyInput

Comment: And here is the actual change I did — https://github.com/clops/SneakyInput/commit/318939caa03ce7435f1a46079464104737441ecc

Answer (score 2):

SneakyInput was written for Cocos2D v0.99/1.0. It probably doesn't work with Cocos2D 2.0 because the API of CCTouchDispatcher might have changed. At least that's what the error message says, that there's no such method `addTargetedDelegate:priority:swallowsTouches:` on CCTouchDispatcher.

Unless you need or want to use Shader Programs I would recommend to use Cocos2D v1.x for the time being. SneakyInput works fine with v1.x

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I have stumbled upon this yesterday night by restarting from scratch with cocos 2d 1.1 :)